# Can't get MFC worker thread to pass hWnd or MDI window pointer to thread

Tags: multithreading, mfc

For some reason passing an hWnd or a pointer of a newly created MDI window cannot be recasted into its original value in the worker thread.  I've tried creating the thread  from the App class, Document class and View class.  All have the same effect.  I'm using a global function for the worker thread.  Funny thing is I'm using the same code I used to do the same thing in an MFC MDI back in 1998 and it worked great back then but doesn't seem to work now.

Perhaps I'm just not seeing the problem.  What is going on here?   What I want to do is simple, create a new View window, capture it's hWnd and pass that hWnd to the worker thread so the worker thread can send messages to the window to print strings and so forth.  I'd like to launch the thread from the Document class.  The compiler is VS2010 and it's being run in Debug.

After reading this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h14y172e%28v=VS.100%29.aspx, I realize that you probably can't pass a pointer to the view class around to worker threads.  So I'm focusing on the hWnds.  In the OnTestConnect block, a valid hWnd is returned as is a valid pointer to the new View window.

Here's the code (from the App class):

```
struct THREADPARMS
{
    HWND hWndView;
    int test;   
};
```

(note, I've tried defining the struct as typedef and with a variable name, all have same result)

```
UINT Starter( LPVOID pParms )
{
    THREADPARMS* pThreadParms = (THREADPARMS* )pParms;

    //This step shouldn't be necesarry but I tried it anyway.  Should
    //be able to use pThreadParms->hWndView without casting.
    //The hWnd value does not come across as valid.  It is valid before sending.
    HWND hWnd = (HWND)pThreadParms->hWndView;

    //The int comes across fine
    int iNum = pThreadParms->test;

     CHFTAppBView* pView = (CHFTAppBView*) CHFTAppBView::FromHandle(hWnd);

     //This bombs with a debug error becuase pView ptr is invalid (though it was
     //valid before sending over
     pView->SendMessage( ID_FILE_PRINT, 0, 0 );

     return 0;

}

void CHFTAppBApp::OnTestConnect()
{
    THREADPARMS* pThreadParms = new THREADPARMS;

     //Create the window
     AfxGetApp()->OnCmdMsg( ID_FILE_NEW, 0, NULL, NULL );

     CMDIFrameWnd* pFrame = (CMDIFrameWnd*)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;
     CMDIChildWnd* pChild = (CMDIChildWnd*)pFrame->GetActiveFrame();
     CHFTAppBView* pView = (CHFTAppBView*)pChild->GetActiveView();

     pThreadParms->hWndView = pView->m_hWnd;
     pThreadParms->test = 10;

     AfxBeginThread( Starter, pThreadParms );
}
```

Part 2

```
//Create the window
AfxGetApp()->OnCmdMsg( ID_FILE_NEW, 0, NULL, NULL );

CMDIFrameWnd* pFrame = (CMDIFrameWnd*)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;
CMDIChildWnd* pChild = (CMDIChildWnd*)pFrame->GetActiveFrame();
CHFTAppBView* pView = (CHFTAppBView*)pChild->GetActiveView();

HWND h = pView->m_hWnd;
SendMessage( h, ID_FILE_PRINT, 0, 0 );
```

I'm trying to determine if the hWnd is valid.  The pView is valid.  Stepping through the code and looking at the pointer stats in the Debugger Watch shows a helathy pointer that references the CView class.  But it does not return a healthy hWnd.  Then Debugger Watch says 'can't evaluate' hWnd memory address and says 'unused=0'.  Running it past IsWindow returns true, however.  Go figure.  Trying to send a CView message to the CView window with that handle just gets ignored.  Why would the GetAvtiveView return a valid pointer but the hWnd in that class return garbage?

Part 3

After some more digging, turns out the HWND is valid though the hwnd variable displays 'unused=???' in the Watch window.  I assume it's valid because the hWnd received in the thread code matches the hWnd attached to the pView pointer in the main code.  The pView pointer the hWnd is taken from is valid as well because Watch recognizes it as a valid CView class pointer by returning the name of the CView class it represents.  There are still two problems however.  One is that even though the system sends a valid hWnd back to a CView window  (pView->m_hWnd), a SendMessage(pView->m_hWnd, ID_FILE_PRINT_PREVIEW, 0, 0,) refuses to work.  The system ignores it.  I expected the FilePrintPreview command in the newly created view window to run.  Second is that FromHandle returns a CWnd object and casting it to a CView fails using all of these methods:

```
UINT ThreadTest1( LPVOID pParms )
{
    THREADPARMS* pThreadParms = (THREADPARMS* )pParms;

    //Returns a CWnd even though the handle is to a valid CView 
    CHFTAppBView* pView2 = (CHFTAppBView*) CHFTAppBView::FromHandle(hWnd);

    //Doesn't seem to do anything.  Still returns a hWnd that the system recognizes as 
    //a CWnd.  That's what reports in the Watch window.
    CHFTAppBView* pView = reinterpret_cast<CHFTAppBView*>(CHFTAppBView::FromHandle(hWnd));

    //Doesn't appear to do anything
    DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST( CHFTAppBView, pView2 );

    //Confirms what watch window says -- it's a CWnd not a CView.
    if ( !pView->IsKindOf( RUNTIME_CLASS(CHFTAppBView) ) )
          AfxMessageBox( "Not CView" );

    ::SendMessage( hWnd, ID_FILE_PRINT, 0, 0 );

    return 0;

}

void CHFTAppBDoc::Main()
{
    AfxGetApp()->OnCmdMsg( ID_FILE_NEW, 0, NULL, NULL );

    THREADPARMS* pThreadParms = new THREADPARMS;

    CMDIFrameWnd* pFrame = (CMDIFrameWnd*)AfxGetApp()->m_pMainWnd;
    CMDIChildWnd* pChild = (CMDIChildWnd*)pFrame->GetActiveFrame();
    CHFTAppBView* pView = (CHFTAppBView*)pChild->GetActiveView();

    pThreadParms->hWndView = pView->m_hWnd;

     AfxBeginThread( ThreadTest1, pThreadParms );

    SendMessage( pView->m_hWnd, ID_FILE_PRINT, 0, 0 );
    //Or
    ::SendMessage( pView->m_hWnd, ID_FILE_PRINT, 0, 0 );

 }
```

So the questions is how can the hWnd be converted to a the correct window pointer in the thread code? Why can't the system cast it to a CView?

Part 4

Probem solved (for now).  Lessons:

1. Cannot pass a CView window pointer to a worker thread.  See link above about this.
2. Use SendMessage to communicate between theads and windows

   //This works from the worker thread now

   THREADPARMS* pThreadParms = (THREADPARMS* )pParms;

   HWND hWnd = static_cast(pThreadParms->hWndView);

   LRESULT lRst = ::SendMessage( pThreadParms->hWnd, WM_GGG, 0, 0 );

   //Or just

   LRESULT lRst = ::SendMessage( pThreadParms->hWnd, WM_GGG, 0, 0 );

   //As well as this from the CDoc method that creates the thread:

   CHFTAppBView* pView = (CHFTAppBView*)pChild->GetActiveView();

   LRESULT lRst = ::SendMessage( pView->m_hWnd, WM_GGG, 0, 0 );

   CView's message map...

   ON_MESSAGE( WM_GGG, kk )
3. Pass HWNDs to worker threads to identify CView windows
4. Cannot cast from CWnd to a lower derrived class (and excpet it to work right).
5. Use ON_MESSAGE in view's message map to capture commands sent with SendMessage (be sure to include the method declaraion as afx_msg in the View's .h file)

All pretty straight forward but for those looking for answers (when faced with a myriad of possible causes) this summary may help...

I still don't completely undertstand why casting FromHandle to a CView worked in my old MFC app and not now.  Perhaps it has something to do with where the code is located.  In the old MFC app it was located in the CView window and in this code in the CDoc class.  CDocument is not derrived from CWnd but CView is.

Anyway, that wraps this problem up. A BIG thank you to all who offered advice -- Nik, Scott, Ulrich and Mark. Your sage advice was very helpful.

Comment: Can you just avoid using a temporary CHFTAppBView and call ::SendMessage(hWnd...) instead?  You're probably running afoul of per-thread handle map issues.

Comment: You would do yourself a favour if you stopped using those C-style casts entirely. Instead, use dynamic_cast when going from baseclass to derived class and static_cast when going from void* to sometype*. Then, you make claims like "does not come across as valid", but fail to tell us about the observations you made that lead you to this conclusion.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions.  Scott, unfortunately, I am trying to determine if the hWnd is at all valid.  I need the hWnd to get a pointer in the thread and I need the worker thread so the GUI doesn't hang when printing and processing data.

Comment: I'd suggest avoiding mixing MFC with the new C++ style casts. MFC implements it's own runtime type information system (it uses C++ features for virtual dispatch but not RTTI)  and has a set of casts that take advantage of it and which you should *probably* use.

Comment: OK, I'll look into that.  That must be new MFC stuff because back in 98 this exact sort of approach worked.  I'd love for that to explain this problem.  I'll keep you guys posted and provide and answer if I can uncover one.

Comment: I'm sure the reason it worked for you previously was because you were single threaded. MFC does keep a map of HWNDs and the CWnd-derived objects they're subclassed to, but it does it in thread-local storage. I'm sure this is intentional because MFC objects aren't meant to be thread-safe. If you call FromHandle from the wrong thread, it can't find it in that thread's table so it has to assign a temporary.

Comment: If you want to print preview of the view, you should code it as `pView->PostMessage(WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_PRINT_PREVIEW, 0);`

Answer (score 5):

You can call `CHFTAppBView::FromHandle(hWnd)` but what you get back isn't a pointer to a `CHFTAppBView`; it's a pointer to a `CWnd`. By casting it, you're telling the compiler "trust me, this is really a pointer to a `CHFTAppBView`. Except it really isn't and you shouldn't treat it as such or pretend that it is.

After all, if a recipe calls for orange juice, then you don't take a lemon, paint it orange, juice it and call it orange juice. Do you?

So what to do? Well, if all you want to do is send the `ID_FILE_PRINT` message, you don't even need a `CWnd` as such. You could just just do:

```
::SendMessage(hWnd, ID_FILE_PRINT, 0, 0);
```

Of course, that's **also** likely to be wrong. What you probably **meant** to do was this:

```
::SendMessage(hWnd, WM_COMMAND, ID_FILE_PRINT, 0);
```

**Update**:

Again, you **CANNOT** do what you are trying to do. Let's go step by step, shall we?

```
//Returns a CWnd even though the handle is to a valid CView 
CHFTAppBView* pView2 = (CHFTAppBView*) CHFTAppBView::FromHandle(hWnd);
```

Right. `CWnd::FromHandle` returns a pointer to a `CWnd`, not to anything else. It is *NOT* giving you back a pointer to your original `CHFTAppBView`. It's giving you a **NEW** `CWnd` which is attached to that same `HWND`. It is **NOT VALID** to cast that to a `CHFTAppBView` because this new `CWnd` is not a `CHFTAppBView`.

```
//Doesn't seem to do anything.  Still returns a hWnd that the system recognizes as 
//a CWnd.  That's what reports in the Watch window.
CHFTAppBView* pView = reinterpret_cast<CHFTAppBView*>(CHFTAppBView::FromHandle(hWnd));
```

Again, `CWnd::FromHandle` returns a pointer to a *new* `CWnd` which knows nothing about `CHFTAppBView`. You are telling the compiler "trust me, this pointer is to a `CHFTAppBView` object!" Except it is *NOT*. It is a pointer to a `CWnd` attached to a `HWND` that is a `CHFTAppBView`.

```
//Doesn't appear to do anything
DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST( CHFTAppBView, pView );
```

This *STILL* wouldn't do anything. First of all, `DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST` returns a pointer to `CHFTAppBView` so right there, you're calling the MFC RTTI functions but not doing anything with the result. But even if you did save the result, it wouldn't help. You would be trying to convert a generic `CWnd` into something it is not.

I'll try to explain this one more time: When you create your view, MFC creates a `CHFTAppBView` object which is associated with the `HWND` of the view. When you call `CWnd::FromHandle` passing in the `HWND` of the view, MFC creates a **NEW** and distinct `CWnd` instance which points to that same `HWND` - that second `CWnd` is **NOT** `CHFTAppBView` and the `HWND` knows nothing about your MFC classes, views, documents or anything else.

You are trying to take the `CWnd *` that `CWnd::FromHandle` returns and hammer it into a `CHFTAppBView *`. No matter how hard you try, this will not work. All you can ever get will be a `CWnd *` and nothing else.

As a sidenote, you also cannot pass MFC objects from one thread to another, so passing the original `CHFTAppBView *` will cause weird issues to crop up, and may lead to hard to track errors.

**Update 2:**

You ask "*Why can't a CWnd object be cast to a window class that derrives from CWnd?*"

Let's start from `CWnd::FromHandle` shall we?

```
CWnd* PASCAL CWnd::FromHandle(HWND hWnd)
{
    CHandleMap* pMap = afxMapHWND(TRUE); //create map if not exist
    ASSERT(pMap != NULL);
    CWnd* pWnd = (CWnd*)pMap->FromHandle(hWnd);

#ifndef _AFX_NO_OCC_SUPPORT
    pWnd->AttachControlSite(pMap);
#endif

    ASSERT(pWnd == NULL || pWnd->m_hWnd == hWnd);
    return pWnd;
}
```

This leads us to `CHandleMap::FromHandle`. The code for that is a bit complicated and posting it here won't help, so let's not clutter things up. But here is what the function does, conceptually:

If a handle is found in the map, it returns it; otherwise, it creates a new `CWnd` and makes that `CWnd` point to the `HWND` you passed in. It then returns a pointer to that `CWnd` to you. But notice, this is **ONLY** a `CWnd`. Nothiong else. So you see, you cannot just convert that returned `CWnd` to something else - even if the something else is derived from a `CWnd` - because what you have is just a `CWnd` and nothing more.

Let's say you have a wife. She is very beautiful and you love her very much. You carry a picture of her in your wallet. Now, when you meet someone and they ask if you are married, you take out your wallet and proudly show them her picture. The person to who you're talking do doesn't think that you are married to the picture. And you don't think that you can magically "convert" the picture into your wife.

The situation here is somewhat similar. `CWnd::FromHandle` gives you a "picture" of sorts. It's good for showing around, but not good for much else. You are asking "why can't I transform the picture to my wife?" The answer is because that's not how pictures work.

Comment: Nik, thank you very much for your thoughts.  I'm tryng to determine if the hWnd I'm getting back from GetActiveWindow (see above) is valid.  It does not appear to be which causes FromHandle to return garbage.

Comment: @brimaa I posted an update. I hope it helps you understand why what you are doing cannot possibly work.

Comment: I can accept that.  However, I know that the C++ style casts with FromHandle *did* work in 1998.  It was code I got from a MSDN support enginer to do exactly what I'm trying to do now and it ran great.  I accept that now in new MFC land that I cannot apparently do what I am trying to do even though this what CWnd::FromHandle says.  "Returns a pointer to a CWnd object when given a handle to a window. If a CWnd object is not attached to the handle, a temporary CWnd object is created and attached."   Is there any insight you can offer to how to convert an hWnd to a valid pointer it represents?

Comment: @brimaa the cast will work in some cases - some very *limited* cases. If all you want to do is call functions that are in `CWnd` (i.e. most of them) then it will be fine, but in that case why not use a `CWnd` anyways? There's really no way to recreate an instance of `CHFTAppBView` given an `HWND` unless you add special code in your `CHFTAppBView` to do that. Think about why: presumably you maintain a lot of state associated with your view. That information isn't available to the window manager and can't just magically appear in the new instance.

Comment: @brimaa: But generally that's *not* how you should do things. Window communications across thread boundaries should be done via Windows messages - and to send those you only need an `HWND` or a bare-bones `CWnd` like that returned from `CWnd::FromHandle`.

Comment: Why can't a CWnd object be cast to a window class that derrives from CWnd?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezc3635w(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I tried the SendMessage it gets ignored.(and I'm poisitive the ON_COMMAND id is in the message map for that window)

Comment: `FromHandle` will return either a pointer to an existing `CWnd` object or a temporary one, depending on certain criteria. One of those criteria is if you're calling it from the same thread the window was created in.

Comment: @brimaa, you can certainly cast a CWnd object to another CWnd derived class, but that won't add any of the missing members to that object. Trying to use such an object is likely to end in pain.

Comment: @brimma I added a bit more explanation. I think that if you combine that with the comments above by Mark Ransom you should have your answer.

Comment: So the problem is is that I take a hWnd that came from a valid CView pointer and can't use it.  The hWnd doesn't work with SendMessage (it gets ignored not sure why) and when I pass it to the thread I can't get the pointer it came from back.  Microsof didn't create a way to go lookup associated pointers by hWnd?  The hWnd came from a valid currently active CView class window.

Comment: @brimaa: It should work fine. Try something like `::ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_HIDE);` and you will see that the window will be hidden. Try sending messages using `LRESULT lRes = ::SendMessage(hWnd, <windows message>, <wParam>, <lParam>);`. Be sure you are sending the correct message and using the correct values for `wParam` and `lParam`. MSDN will be useful to you in determining what those are.

Comment: Thank you.  I'll look over the code again and let you know what I find.  I agree it *should* work but doesn't seem to.

Comment: @brimaa: in your thread, make sure you send messages to `pThreadParms->hWndView` and not just `hWnd` ;)

Comment: Nik, got it working.  Please see part 4 above.  Thanks, again!